# How do I add a wallet to web3-react without using an injected browser extension?

Tags: web3js, metamask

So essentially I am not using the Metamask browser extension for my usecase and instead, I'm initializing a wallet using `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(private-key)` to add the wallet. I'm also using infura to connect to the kovan test network. The codebase I'm adding to is using web3-react to manage state, but currently it discovers your wallet only if you add it through connecting it with the Metamask browser extension or any other wallet extension/login. How do I add my programmatically added wallet to my we3-react manager?